Complete survey or sample survey?
We have a service that started in April 2023 and has continued to the present.
We would like to perform an analysis to verify the results, but the data
is only available from April 2023 to August 2023.
We are able to obtain all of this data, but when we analyze it, will it be a perfect survey or a sample survey?
If it is an perfect survey, is statistical testing not necessary, just checking the percentages, etc.?
I am thinking that if I want to examine only this range of data, it would be a perfect survey, and if I want to predict the data to date as well, it would be a sample survey.

Please see if the https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit for the question

It's a sample survey. We can understand the complete survey as the population of the survey. In this case, from 4/2023 to 9/2023 means a part of it. So it is just a sample survey
However, we can find some distribution and make predictions using a sample survey.
This knowledge is from my Statistics & Probability. I hope it helps you well.
